Does there exist a positive sequence with these two properties?

Let $\{x\}$ denote the fractional part of $x$. Does there exist a sequence with all positive terms $(a_n)_{n\geq 1}$ such that $$\lim_{n\to\infty} \{(-1)^n a_n\}=1\ \ \ \text{and}\ \ \ \lim_{n\to\infty} \left\{\frac{(-1)^n a_n}{\sqrt{2}}\right\}=1$$

I tried $a_{n}=n+(-1)^{n+1}2^{-n}$. We have $$(-1)^na_{n}= (-1)^nn-1+(1-2^{-n}) $$ Thus $$\{(-1)^na_n\}=1-2^{-n}\to 1$$
Any help will be highly appreciated. Thank you!

What's the point of writing $a_n^2$? It's never a good idea to overcomplicate the notation.

@jjagmath Thanks. I have fixed it. Please answer.

It is obvious that it exists. So presumably your question is about finding something explicit, right?

@JohnB Thanks. Soory, but how is it obvious?

It follows from the fact that $1$ and $\sqrt2$ are rationally independent.

@JohnB So if we had some rational number in place of $\sqrt{2}$, say $a/b$ then also we can get a sequence?

@JohnB How rationally independence of $1$ and $\sqrt{2}$ give us such a sequence? Is there any result or theorem? Please share. I am not aware.

I will write this in an answer.

@JohnB Thats great. Thank you so much. I will be really obliged to accept your answer.

While the answer by @John B is of course correct, I wanted to give a simple explicit construction of such a sequence.

Ignoring the $(-1)^n$ for a moment, you essentially want multiples of $\sqrt2$ that are very close (but slightly below) integers. For example, let $(\frac{p_n}{q_n})_n$ be the sequence of lower convergengents of the continued fraction of $\sqrt2$, i.e. those with $\frac{p_n}{q_n}<\sqrt2$. Let $(\varepsilon_n)_n$ be any sequence converging to $0$, with $0<\varepsilon_n<1$ for all $n$. Then define $$a_n=p_n-(-1)^n\varepsilon_n.$$ We then have, if $n$ is even, $$\{(-1)^na_n\}=\{a_n\}=\{p_n-\varepsilon_n\}=1-\varepsilon_n\xrightarrow{n\to\infty}1,$$ and similarly if $n$ is odd. Hence $\lim_{n\to\infty}\{(-1)^na_n\}=1$. For the second limit we have, by the general theory of continued fractions, $\sqrt2q_n-p_n<\frac1{q_n}$, $q_n-\frac1{\sqrt2q_n}<\frac{p_n}{\sqrt2}<q_n$, which implies for even $n$ that $$\left\{\frac{(-1)^na_n}{\sqrt2}\right\}=\left\{\frac{p_n-\varepsilon_n}{\sqrt2}\right\}>1-\frac1{\sqrt2q_n}-\frac{\varepsilon_n}{\sqrt2}\xrightarrow{n\to\infty}1.$$ Again the case for odd $n$ is handled similarly, which proves the result.

Note that there is nothing special about $\sqrt{2}$ here, the same argument works for any real number instead. (If the number is rational, the convergents become constant, of course, but that doesn't matter.) You also don't have to work with continued fractions, you just need any reasonably-well-approximating sequence. Dirichlet's approximation theorem guarantees that such sequences exist, with the exact inequalities that I used in the proof. I just wanted to give a very explicit example.

($+1$) Thanks. But what if we have a rational number $a/b>1$ in place of $\sqrt{2}$? Please explain it. Thank you.

As I mention in the last paragraph, the same construction works in this case as well. Or more explicitly: Take $a_n=a-(-1)^n\varepsilon_n$.

But please see the comment of @John B. He is saying that it works only for irrational number and not for a rational number.

They state that their construction only works for irrational numbers (which is obvious since they rely on Weyl's theorem). But that doesn't imply that the result is false for rational numbers.

In your answer by the general theory of continued fractions, $\sqrt2q_n-p_n<\frac1{q_n}$. Is this true if we replace $\sqrt{2}$ by rational number $a/b>1$?

Yes, sure, because then you can simply take $\frac{p_n}{q_n}=\frac ab$, so that $\frac ab\cdot b-a=0<\frac1b=\frac1{q_n}$. As I said in my first comment, in the case of a rational number $\frac ab$, my construction simplifies to $a_n=a-(-1)^n\varepsilon_n$.

Let's forget first about $(-1)^n$.
Given $n\in\mathbb N$, take $c_n>0$ such that $|\{c_n\}-1|<\frac1n$. Of course,
$$
|\{m+c_n\}-1|=|\{c_n\}-1|<\frac1n\tag1
$$
for any positive integer $m>0$. On the other hand, one can take $m=m_n$ so that, additionally,
$$
\left\lvert\left\{\frac{m_n+c_n}{\sqrt2}\right\}-1\right\rvert<\frac1n.\tag2
$$
This is a consequence of the rational independence of $1$ and $\sqrt2$ (see for example this article in the wikipedia).
For $x_n=m_n+c_n$ we clearly have
$$
\{x_n\}\to1 \quad\text{and}\quad \{x_n/\sqrt2\}\to1
$$
when $n\to\infty$, in view of $(1)$ and $(2)$.
Now let's go back to the $(-1)^n$.
One can, similarly, and for the same reason, construct a negative sequence $y_n$ such that
$$
\{y_n\}\to1 \quad\text{and}\quad \{y_n/\sqrt2\}\to1
$$
when $n\to\infty$.
Finally, define $a_{2n}=x_n$ and $a_{2n-1}=y_n$ for each $n\in\mathbb N$. Then
$$
\{a_n\}\to1 \quad\text{and}\quad \{a_n/\sqrt2\}\to1
$$
when $n\to\infty$.

($+1$) Thanks. But what if we have a rational number $a/b>1$ in place of $\sqrt{2}$?

It works if you replace $\sqrt2$ by another irrational number, but not by a rational number.

Thank you. Thats surprising for me. But why it does not work when we replace $\sqrt{2}$ by a rational number. Please explain a bit. This is my last question.

For that you really need to have a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weyl_sequence (or at some equivalent description and its proof), but in simple terms the point is that the sequence $c_m={m\alpha}$ is dense in $[0,1]$ if and only if $\alpha$ is irrational (for example if $\alpha=1/\sqrt2$ as above).

Sorry to confuse you. I am asking that whether by any method we can find a sequence $a_n$ when we replace $\sqrt{2}$ by any rational number? Thanks.

I already replied to that above: It works if you replace $\sqrt2$
by another irrational number, but not by a rational number.

Sorry, but according to the another answer it is being claimed that it is true for any rational number as well

About that you need to ask the other colleague (I do like the answer!). But perhaps I should clarify that I am answering referring to the argument in my answer, that is, the argument can be used replacing $\sqrt2$ by any other irrational number, but not by a rational number (unless some changes are made)!
